# How to modify TL431 current limiter to work with 80V bus?

Tags: high-voltage, short-circuit, current-limiting, voltage-reference

I referred following circuit from TL431 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1594286282247&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTL431%253Fqgpn%253Dtl431)

TL431 max voltage at cathode is 36V.

since circuit has only a transistor , how to modify this circuit to work with 80V at input(Vi bat).

output current should limited to 5mA. (5-10% error is allowable ) at 80V (load regulation 5% allowable).

application - short circuit protection.

[image: schematic from data sheet]

Comment: Did you try to calculate the cathode voltage for your circuit? What did you come up with?

Comment: *TL431 max voltage at cathode is 36V.* So you're saying that the cathode voltage potential must not be higher than 36V? So if I power the circuit from a 9 V battery (way below 36 V) and put it in a closed metal box, apply a +1000 V potential to that metal box, the TL431 will break? How can the TL431 "know" that it is at +1000 V? It sits in a closed metal box and has **no connection to ground**. Maybe "the maximum voltage **between anode and kathode cannot exceed 36 V**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how to modify this circuit to work with 80V at input(Vi bat).*

The [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1594288168669&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) won't see anything like 80 volts between any of its terminals. The maximum voltage between cathode and reference pin is limited to around 1 volt maximum (BJT \$V_{BE}\$) and, the normal operating voltage between the reference pin and the anode is 2.5 volts. That would make \$R_{CL}\$ in your circuit 500 ohms for a 5 mA current limit.

If you are worried about transients etc. you can use TVS diodes connected across the pins but I can't see you having a problem that would normally need them.

If you need to put your mind at rest I suggest you try simulating the circuit.

Comment: I have a doubt, my supply voltage Vbatt will change time to time assume 20V, 50V or 80V, same time load resistance will change as well, sometime it will draw 2mA, 3mA or 1mA, but max load current should be limited to 5mA, will this circuit limit the output load current to 5mA always when Vbatt changes from 20V to 80V?

Comment: @kobi89 The TL431 will adjust it self to ensure that 2.5 volts appears across \$R_{CL}\$. If you have a simulator (they are free these days mainly), I would suggest you put your mind at rest by using it.